# Flutter: Accidentaly created my whole UI on 360x780. How can I make it to be evenly resized on other phone screens?

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, screen, responsive

I have a Samsung A40 which has a screen size of 1080x2340. When I've created my Flutter application I used this phone, which means, I created my app using 360 as max width, and 780 as max height. I want my application to be able to automatically resize itself according to this information. How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing with one device in mind is not the proper way of UI development. But still for your use case, if you just want to support your one device, you can make use of the package [`flutter_screenutil`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) .

Use  `ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 360, height: 780);`

But again, since your hardcoded values are spread across different places, you might need to revisit them.